# how to implement relationships between models with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

1º user **John** has many gifts

**user.rb**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :gifts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
 end
```

**gift.rb**

```
 class Gift
      include Mongoid::Document
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :orders ,dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
     end
```

2º user **Anthony** buy a gift to **John** and make a new order

```
class Order
   include Mongoid::Document
   belongs_to :gift
   belongs_to :user
  end
```

Now the user Anthony wants to access all his sales made.

**The challenge here is that a user may have two roles, buyer or a seller.**

How should I develop relationships between models that Antonio can access his sales made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Models structure

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :gifts, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
end

class Gift
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gifted_to, :class_name => 'User'

  has_one :order ,dependent: :destroy, :autosave => true
end

class Order
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :gift
  # below associtation is just for quicker ref 
  # otherwise you can have access to it via gift also
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: How can one gift can have many orders associated.. can you give any usecase of same?

Comment: @hyperrjas okk .. no problem !